# React Native useRef with custom TextInput and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

I am getting the following warning on my custom input component:

`'TextInput' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof TextInput'?`

When referencing it using `useRef` like so:

`const lastNameRef = useRef<TextInput>(null)`

Here's what `TextInput` looks like:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react"
import {
  TextInput as ReactTextInput,
  TextInputProps as ReactTextInputProps,
} from "react-native"
import styled from "styled-components/native"
import {
  compose,
  space,
  SpaceProps,
  color,
  ColorProps,
  layout,
  LayoutProps,
  flexbox,
  FlexboxProps,
  border,
  BorderProps,
  position,
  PositionProps,
  background,
  BackgroundProps,
  typography,
  TypographyProps,
} from "styled-system"

export type TextInputProps = ReactTextInputProps &
  SpaceProps &
  ColorProps &
  LayoutProps &
  FlexboxProps &
  BorderProps &
  PositionProps &
  BackgroundProps &
  TypographyProps

const StyledTextInput = styled.TextInput<TextInputProps>`
  ${compose(
    space,
    color,
    layout,
    flexbox,
    border,
    position,
    background,
    typography,
  )};
`

export const TextInput = forwardRef<ReactTextInput, TextInputProps>(
  (
    {
      fontFamily = "body",
      fontWeight = "regular",
      fontSize = 1,
      color = "text",
      ...rest
    },
    ref,
  ) => {
    return (
      <StyledTextInput
        {...{ ref, fontFamily, fontWeight, fontSize, color, ...rest }}
      />
    )
  },
)
```

I am forwarding the reference, which is what should get rid of that warning.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is right in your error message, you need to use `typeof TextInput`.

```
const lastNameRef = useRef<typeof TextInput>(null);
```

The reason why you need to this for your component and not for `useRef<ReactTextInput>` is that one is a function component and the other is a class component. In typescript, a class is both the underlying class object and the type which represents an instance of that class.  So you can use `ReactTextInput` as a type.  Your `TextInput` is a function so it's just a variable and not a type.  The actual type for that variable is a very long definition starting with `React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<ReactTextInputProps & SpaceProps<....` but you don't need to know that.  You can access the type with `typeof TextInput`.

Comment: Having tried to use this, I think that since `TextInput`'s type is a return object from ForwardRef, you need to wrap the type in `ElementRef` (type imported from React) to extract the underlying element, like this: `useRef<ElementRef<typeof TextInput>>`, else the ref.current's type will be that of a forwardRef object (properties like `displayName` etc) and will not have the actual native element methods like `focus()` etc